# How to find polynomial roots correctly?

Tags: matlab, polynomials

Consider a polynomial such as:

```
p = [1 -9 27 -27];
```

obviously the real root is 3:

```
polyval(p,3)

0
```

While using the `roots` function

```
q = roots([1 -9 27 -27]);
```

with `format short`:

```
q =

   3.0000 + 0.0000i
   3.0000 + 0.0000i
   3.0000 - 0.0000i
```

and to check if the the roots are real:

```
bsxfun(@eq,ones(size(q)),isreal(q))

0
0
0
```

And even worse with `format long` I get:

```
roots([1 -9 27 -27])

ans =

  3.000019414068325 + 0.000000000000000i
  2.999990292965843 + 0.000016813349886i
  2.999990292965843 - 0.000016813349886i
```

How can I calculate roots of a polynomial correctly?

Comment: Minor note: your check to see if the roots are real is not correct. `isreal(q)` gives `false` if the _array_ `q` is complex. But some entries may have zero imaginary part. In fact, `isreal(q)` gives `false`, whereas `for x = q(:).', isreal(x), end` gives `true`, `false`, `false`. The first entry of `q` is real, the others are not, and `q` as a whole is not real

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to floating point inaccuracies. Have a look at this post for details:
[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

One thing you can do is to round off the answer/s upto some decimal places like this:

```
q = round(roots([1 -9 27 -27]), 4) % rounding off to 4 decimal places
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, please check my comment below.

Comment: Both answers are great and unfortunately I couldn't accept both. So I decided to accept your answer because I am using this in my code. And give @LuisMendo answer (+1) because I learned new things. Thank you both.

Answer (score 6):

You may have to work symbolically. You need the Symbolic Math Toolbox for that.

1. Define the polynomial as a symbolic function. You can (a) use [`poly2sym`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/poly2sym.html) to generate the symbolic polynomial from its coefficients. Or (b) better yet, define the symbolic function directly using a string. That way you avoid the loss of accuracy that may result from representing the coefficients as `double`.
2. Use [`solve`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html), which symbolically solves algebraic equations.

Code with option (a):

```
p = [1 -9 27 -27];
ps = poly2sym(p);
rs = solve(ps);
```

Code with option (b):

```
ps = sym('x^3-9*x^2+27*x-27');
rs = solve(ps);
```

In either case, the result is symbolic:

```
>> rs
rs =
 3
 3
 3
```

You may want to convert to numeric values using

```
r = double(rs);
```

In your example, this gives

```
>> format long
>> r
r =
     3
     3
     3
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am performing this for say 1000 polynomials with different coefficients and degrees. Regarding efficiency, does it make sense to use option(a) in your answer or just use the round function as @sardar_usama mentioned?

Comment: I think the `round` function is faster, but there is the trade off between accuracy and efficiency.

Comment: No need to use `poly2sym` I think. This works fine: `roots(sym([1 -9 27 -27]))`. The `roots` function doesn't appear to be overloading for symbolic types but the underlying functions it calls are. There's also [`root`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/root.html) in the Symbolic Math toolbox that can be used instead of the more general `solve`.

Comment: @horchler Thanks for the info!

Comment: @NKN Yes, it makes sense that `round` is faster (but may be less accurate)

Answer (score 0):

This is very specific to your polynomial. In general you have to expect that a root of multiplicity `m` has a relative floating point error of magnitude `mu^(1/m)` where `mu=1e-15` is the machine precision. In this case the multiplicity is `m=3`, thus the error in the range of `10^(-5)`. Which is exactly the scale of the errors in your results.

That this happens here with clear integer coefficients is a result of the method matlab uses, it computes the eigenvalues of the companion matrix, and the eigenvalue algorithm will transform the integer matrix into a proper floating point matrix with corresponding rounding errors in the first step of the algorithm.

Other algorithms have empirical tests for multiplicities and associated clusters of approximative roots and thus are able to correct this error. In this case you could achieve this by replacing each root by the average of the 3 roots.

---

Mathematically, you have some polynomial

```
p(x)=(x-a)^m*q(x)
```

with a root at `x=a` of multiplicity `m`. Due to floating point operations, the solver effectively "sees" a polynomial

```
p(x)+e(x)
```

where the coefficients of `e(x)` have a size that is the magnitude of the coefficients of `p` times `mu`. Close to the root `a`, this perturbed polynomial can be effectively replaced by

```
(x-a)^m*q(a)+e(a) = 0  <==>  (x-a)^m = -e(a)/q(a)
```

so that the solutions form an m-pointed regular polygon or star centered at `a` with radius `|e(a)/q(a)|^(1/m)` which should be in the region of `|a|*mu^(1/m)`.